# How can I create a HostListener within a directive for nativescript?

Tags: angular, event-handling, addeventlistener, directive, nativescript-angular

Right now I'm trying to create a directive to add to all my buttons where the button get's disabled when it gets tapped. I can create this by creating a tap event on all my buttons individually in each component but that's inefficient code use. I created a directive on angular to disable the buttons, however, it does not translate over to Nativescript. This is what I did:

```
  selector: '[appPreventDoubleClick]',
})
export class PreventDoubleClickDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('click') clickEvent() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Then on each html button I add the directive:
`appPreventDoubleClick`

Doing the same on Nativescript doesn't work, as adding a directive without a container and a template makes the buttons disappear. When I add those, the buttons return, however, I'm unsure as to where to place the Host listener, or if I should even be using host listener.

The Nativescript documentation shows that an event listener should be added directly to the button object within the component, but I'm not sure how that translates to a directive:
https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/events

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add appPreventDoubleClick to the directives list of the component

```
@Component({ 

... 

directives: [appPreventDoubleClick] 
})
```

Try the below

```
   import {Directive, Input, HostListener, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPreventDoubleClick]'
})
export class PreventDoubleClickDirective {
 

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }


  @HostListener('click')
  click() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.disabled =true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.disabled=false;
    }, 1000);
  }
  
}
```

[SampleCode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hostlistener-directive-medium-jv47wx)

Comment: This is almost exactly what I have for my angular front end (except for the input) and it works, however, this doesn't work for Nativescript. I tried with the small changes you made, but it still didn't work

Comment: That input is not needed in ur case. I removed it and updated the answer.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Like I said, it works for angular front end but not nativescript.

Comment: Have u added appPreventDoubleClick to the directives list of the component?

Comment: I added it to the directives list of the module, but i don't think i have to add it to the component directly, I don't have to do it in angular front end, and nothing in the nativescript docs indicated i had to do it in there

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/NativeScript/docs/issues/431

Comment: Nativescript was being too difficult and their documentation too vague with too many errors in their examples, so I created a work around instead where I put the disable code into a service and tapping the button calls that function which changes a behavior subject which hides the button instead